# Give Admin Permissions for select Outlook Calendar events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I am a case manager that uses Outlook calendar to book events with clients. Often times I have other people book appointments for me. It is a very complicated and convoluted process to have someone else book an appointment for me on my calendar without giving them permission. It involves several calendars and a confusing process of switching back-and-forth between calendars, of overlaying calendars, and invitations that can get your sleep lost. In the process is different depending on if you’re on desktop or web browser. Is there a way that I can give permission to others for certain categories of event on my calendar. I do Not want everyone to have infinite editing permissions on all events on my calendars, instead I would just like some people to edit some events on my calendar. Is there a simple way of doing this that does not involve other integrated apps? Simple enough that I can teach people quickly. We have a lot of staff turnover and they are not necessarily technically fluent.

I have been racking my brain over this for the past year and I cannot figure out a simple solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there seems to be no option that could set the permission of single event. As a workaround, we could try to set the private item(right-click the event>choose Private)

[image]

So that only the delegate who sets "Delegate can see my private items" could edit these items.

[image]